# Flex not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q55az1ja/)

For some reason the `flex` property is not working in IE. I am not sure where the issue is, please can some one look into this.

I cannot make fixed width as the `div`s will be dynamically added/removed.

```css
#stores-table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background: #8ff;
  display: table;
}
#tr {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
}
#td {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
#stores-table #thead {
  background: #edece9;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  width: 650px\9;
  min-width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.store_name,
.store_state,
.store_phone,
.store_add,
.store_state,
.store_city,
.store_zip,
.store_direction {
  /* width: 20%; */
  /* display: inline-block; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  width: 20%;
  /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  /* width: 25%\9; */
  /* display: inline-block\9; */
  min-width: 10px;
  display: inline-block !important;
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="stores-table">
  <div id="thead">
    <div id="td" class="store_name">Store Name</div>
    <div id="td" class="store_add">Address</div>
    <div id="td" class="store_city">City</div>
    <div id="td" class="store_direction">Directions</div>
  </div>
  <div id="tbody">
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">550 Eglinton Ave W Eglinton</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 550 Eglinton Ave W Eglinton Toronto, Ontario M5N1B6">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">2345 Yonge St The Edison Centre</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 2345 Yonge St The Edison Centre Toronto, Ontario M4P1E4">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">523 St. Clair Ave W St Clair &amp; Bathurst</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 523 St. Clair Ave W St Clair &amp; Bathurst Toronto, Ontario M6C1A1">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1507 Yonge St Yonge &amp; St.Clair</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 1507 Yonge St Yonge &amp; St.Clair Toronto, Ontario M4T1Z2">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">759 Mount Pleasant Rd Mt. Pleasant Road</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 759 Mount Pleasant Rd Mt. Pleasant Road Toronto, Ontario M4S2N4">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">3110 Bathurst Street Lawrence Plaza</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">North York</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 3110 Bathurst Street Lawrence Plaza North York, Ontario M6A2A1">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1500 Avenue Rd Avenue &amp; Lawrence</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 1500 Avenue Rd Avenue &amp; Lawrence Toronto, Ontario M5M3X2">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1840 Eglinton Ave W Eglinton &amp; Dufferin</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 1840 Eglinton Ave W Eglinton &amp; Dufferin Toronto, Ontario M6E2J4">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">292 Dupont St Spadina &amp; Dupont</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 292 Dupont St Spadina &amp; Dupont Toronto, Ontario M5R1V9">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Fortinos</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">700 Lawrence Ave W</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">North York</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Fortinos 700 Lawrence Ave W North York, Ontario M6A3B4">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Loblaws</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">650 Dupont St</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Loblaws 650 Dupont St Toronto, Ontario M6G4B1">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Metro</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">656 Eglinton Ave E</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Metro 656 Eglinton Ave E Toronto, Ontario M4P1P1">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1531 Bayview Ave 1531 Bayview</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 1531 Bayview Ave 1531 Bayview Toronto, Ontario M4G3B5">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">3089 Dufferin St Dufferin &amp; Lawrence</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 3089 Dufferin St Dufferin &amp; Lawrence Toronto, Ontario M6A2S7">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">2340 Eglinton Ave W. West Side Mall</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 2340 Eglinton Ave W. West Side Mall Toronto, Ontario M6M1S6">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Shoppers Drug Mart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">565 Sherbourne St Sherbourne &amp; Howard</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Shoppers-Drug-Mart 565 Sherbourne St Sherbourne &amp; Howard Toronto, Ontario M4X1W7">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Metro</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1411 Lawrence Ave W</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">North York</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Metro 1411 Lawrence Ave W North York, Ontario M6L1A4">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tr">
      <div id="td" class="store_name">Walmart</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_add">1305 Lawrence Ave W</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_city">Toronto</div>
      <div id="td" class="store_direction"><a target="_blank" class="small button radius getDir" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Walmart 1305 Lawrence Ave W Toronto, Ontario M6L1A5">Directions</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using? http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @tenderloin :IE9   / OR any alternative for flex ?

Comment: To begin with, you are re-using IDs...you can't do that. Try switching to classes for repeating properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have find an Alternate for Flex, 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kzgn78n5/3/)

```
HTML : 

<div class="Table">
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 3</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




CSS : 

    .Table {
        display: table;
        border : 1px solid #f00;
        width : 100%;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```